# Not able to load background-image to a div in html/css

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have been having this issue for awhile now. I'm using reactjs and trying to add a background image to a div tag

```
<div className="ficon"></div>
```

in the css file I have

```
  .ficon {
    max-width: 100px;
    max-height:100px;
    background-image: url('/Users/anthonychoi98/Documents/GitHub/portfolio/src/images/folder-icon (1).png');
}
```

The thing is that it works when the url address is http or from the internet, but not when it's local in my computer. I tried using the relative path and that didn't work either. It compiles without any errors or warnings, it just doesnt display the image. I know the url is right because it works when I use it as an image.

```
<img src="/Users/anthonychoi98/Documents/GitHub/portfolio/src/images/folder-icon (1).png"/>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you add ``height`` and ``width`` instead of ``max-height`` and ``max-width``?

Comment: not sure what you mean but changing it to height/width didnt change anything  ;(

Comment: Okay. Can you change your link like this``url('../src/images/folder-icon (1).png')``?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a relative path to the image file? For example:

```
<img src="src/images/folder-icon (1).png" />
```

Also consider removing the space from the filename.